# Change Default printer not working on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-applications, printing

I am trying to shift the default printer while printing from my application.This code is working on development but not working when application is hosted on IIS 7.

```
       ManagementObjectCollection objManagementColl;
      //   class used to invoke the query for specified management collection
        ManagementObjectSearcher objManagementSearch = new   ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

      //   invokes the specified query and returns the resulting collection
        objManagementColl = objManagementSearch.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject objManage in objManagementColl)
        {
            if (objManage["Name"].ToString() == "EPSON Bill")  // compares the name of printers
            {
                objManage.InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter", null); // invoke [SetDefaultPrinter] method
                break;
            }
        }
```